# Combine DER formated certificate and key into one file

Tags: openssl, der

With PEM simple `cat` works fine:

```
cat key.pem cert.pem >cert+key.pem
```

And extration works fine

```
openssl pkey -text -noout -in cert+key.pem  # OK
openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert+key.pem  # OK
```

But with DER this does not work.

```
cat cert.der key.der >cert+key.der
openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert+key.der -inform der  # OK
openssl pkey -text -noout -in cert+key.der -inform der  # ERROR
```

```
Can't open RBBR11912AZ000035.der for reading, No such file or directory
4612937152:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('RBBR11912AZ000035.der','rb')
4612937152:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
unable to load key
```

The order makes sense. OpenSSL can parse only first key or cert.

How to properly concatenate cert + key in DER format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) is a encoding for a single certificate.  Just like a BMP file is a format for a single bitmap image.  So it doesn't support multiple certificates in one file.

You can think of [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) file as a "container" format.  It contains one or more base64 DER formatted certificates (along with other things like private keys).

Another certificate container format is [PKCS12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) (.pfx) which can be thought of like a binary version of the PEM format.